# ASP.NET MVC 3 helper to render table

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and would like to know is here any helper which could help to render simple table? For example I call `@Html.DisplayTableFor(model)` and helper takes all model properties and render them as html table.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this, unless you write your own helper class. You'll have to do it manually, and a side note I'd avoiding using tables in your UIs theres much better ways to display most data.

Comment: Give me example what is better than Table for displaying tabular data?

Comment: Take a look at MVCContrib's `Grid` Component - http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Grid

Answer (score 2):

You can use the webgrid option:

```
@{
    var grd = new WebGrid(options);
}
@grd.GetHtml();
```

You can find a tutorial here:

- [WebGrid WebHelper in ASP.NET MVC 3 RC](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=615).